# How to write replace string function inside Yii2 query

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a MySQL query which selects column based on the replace string values passed to a column

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE REPLACE(column_name, '.', '') = 'value';
```

In the above query i remove dot values from the `column_name` of the table and I pass values with out dots and it works fine.

Now i need to make this query to work in Yii2 query

I have a query in Yii2 like below,

```
$Table= Table::findOne([ column_name => \Yii::$app->request->post('value')]);
```

How can i make the first query condition work in Yii2 query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Like

```
$Table= Table::find()
      ->where(["REPLACE(column_name, '.', '')" => \Yii::$app->request->post('value')])
      ->one();
```

Refer [Yii2 DB Query Builder Guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder)

Answer (score 1):

a simple way is the use of string format in where condition

```
  $Table= Table::find()->where("REPLACE(column_name, '.', '') = 'value'")->one();
```

you can find useful sample in this guide

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder